# Does adding a parameter to a function definition require a new major version?

Tags: semantic-versioning

Using Semantic Versioning, if one of the function of my API undergoes the following change:

```
foo(a, b)
->
foo(a, b, c) //c optional
```

Does that require a new major version, or can it be passed under a minor version?

Answer (score 0):

[Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/) says:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
>   MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>   PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

If your extra param is optional, it requires a **MINOR** version change. Else, it requires a **MAJOR** version change.

Comment: Even if the extra third parameter is optional, depending on the language a call to the function with three parameters will change the behaviour of the API (exception/ignorance -> actually doing something). What about it?

Comment: To avoid a major release, you could setup a new function, say `fooFunction(a,b,c)` (containing all the code) and make `foo(a,b)` call `fooFunction(a,b,null)`. But as far as I know, if your API supports optional params, the language the call comes from is irrelevant. It will work. The client wouldn't know how many parameters you need anyway. So it all breaks down to how your API reacts to a variable number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

According to http://semver.org/

> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
>   MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>   PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

So if you change the function it'a a major change.

but if you were overloading the function with another signature and not breaking compatibility .. it's a minor

Answer (score 0):

Using the strictest interpretation of semver 2.0, I would expect that to be a breaking (i.e. major) change. You're changing the signature of a public method, that means making an incompatible API change.

Using a shallow understanding of optional parameters, I'd say that's a backwards-compatible (i.e. minor) change. The method can still be called in all the ways it was previously, so no code that calls the old method will fail to compile.

However, after doing some more digging into how C# seems to handle optional parameters and method groups, I've settled on the conclusion that it's a breaking (i.e. major) change. C# allows higher-order operations (e.g. passing "delegates"), and changing a method to add an optional parameter breaks code that passes that method as a delegate.

To demonstrate this, this compiles:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var _ = TakesBar(Bar);
}
static int TakesBar(Func<int, int> bar) => bar(0);
static int Bar(int x) => x + 1;
```

However, after changing the signature of `Bar` to add an optional parameter at the end, it no longer compiles, because `Bar` now has the wrong signature to be passed to TakesBar:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var _ = TakesBar(Bar);
}
static int TakesBar(Func<int, int> bar) => bar(0);
static int Bar(int x, int y = 0) => x + y + 1;
```

In contrast, this still works:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var _ = TakesBar(Bar);
}
static int TakesBar(Func<int, int> bar) => bar(0);
static int Bar(int x) => x + 1;
static int Bar(int x, int y) => x + y + 1;
```